# ploting RGB image in gnuplot?

Tags: image, matlab, gnuplot

im working on RGB image segmentation, so to extract the the pixels of image i used matlabe in the flowing way :

```
>>I=imread('clown.jpg');
>>csvwrite('data.txt',I);
```

after that i tried to plot the text file which containe the pixels using gnuplot but it doesn't give me the image as the originale one ? i plot the file in gnuplot with this commande:

```
gnuplot>>plot'data.txt' matrix with image
```

i converted the data in the text file to unsigned char but still the same problem

can anyone tell me why it is not as the original ?

Comment: actually, you don't even have to convert it into text... see this blog post : http://www.gnuplotting.org/images-within-a-graph/

Comment: Why do you ask the same question again? I already gave you an example how you van plot image data directly!

Comment: Mr.Christoph i deleted it because it wasn't describing the problem exactly and i writed a new one to be more clair.
the problem is that i have a txt file not png image, why txt file because i want to classifie it usinf FCM and then plot ot again.
when the image wasnt as i expected i tried to see the original how is it, thinking that it maybe the source of error. and that why i tried to plot it using the file containing the pixels, and it wasn't like the original thats why the fuzzy cmean out put wasnt correct. 
i doubt it from the way i plot image so thats why i posted this question.